# How feature works with panels?

Tags: 7, panels, features

I have created cusotm layout with panels on my dev and staging site. I added a class to panels region and exported using feature. Then I enabled it on stage site. But there was no changes on stage site. Is there anything more needed for panels update using features? Or have anyone a documentation on features with panels, panelizer and panopoly module?

I exported Panels: mylayout (Default Config)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that, any update from feature module works only if that was created using feature module.